# SaltStack: Is there a way to make the minion use a different SNI for publishing and returning?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm running a Salt master in a very constrained Kubernetes environment where the ingress controller only listens on a single port.

Can I configure my minion so that it uses a different SNI for publishing and returning?

e.g. publish https://salt-master.publish.com
ret  https://salt-master.ret.com

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible. salt is setup to pay attention and to make sure that the information goes to the same master that it picked up from.